# KML & Google maps error

Tags: maps, kml

I've created a program in Java to create a KML file. The output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
<name>Evidence File</name>
<description>London</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>51.522416,-0.131836,0<coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

However, when I import it into Google maps - I have the error:

> We could not finish uploading your file. No changes have been made to
>   the map.

Can anyone see any errors that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing `coordinates` tag is missing a '/', i.e. it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
    <Placemark>
        <name>Evidence File</name>
        <description>London</description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>51.522416,-0.131836,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Comment: Cheers JonoB. Simple mistake. Just needed another set of eyes to look at it.